# Convert data in to date format in python but unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python

i have below python Code

```
def add_value_by_date(file_name, start_column, start_row, value):
    with closing(load_workbook(filename=file_name)) as wb:
    ws = wb.active
    start_row =int(start_row)
    start_column= int(start_column)
    for i in value:
        i = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%m/%d/%Y")
        ws.cell(row=start_row, column=start_column).value = i
        start_row += 1
    wb.save(file_name)
```

i get an erorr after i try to convert value `i = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, "%m/%d/%Y")`

**A data in my list**

> ['06/26/2018', '06/26/2018']

**Erorr  Message :**

> IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the code.

Specifically,

> ```
> with closing(load_workbook(filename=file_name)) as wb:
> ws = wb.active
> ...
> ```

The block under `with` statement should be indented!